# SQL determine business days passed since beginning of month using calendar table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a calendar table with all dates and a column indicating whether its a business day.
For example

| Date | Business_Day |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 | False |
| 1/2/2021 | False |
| 1/3/2021 | True |

...
I have another table with dates and would like to determine how many business days have elapsed since the beginning of that month.
For example:

| Date | Business_Days_Passed |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | 0 |
| 1/2/2022 | 0 |
| 1/3/2022 | 1 |
| 1/4/2022 | 2 |
| 1/15/2022 | 10 |
| 2/2/2022 | 2 |
| 2/11/2022 | 9 |
| 2/12/2022 | 9 |

Is there a way to do this using standard sql?  I was thinking of creating some kind of UDF but there may be an easier way?  This using snowflake so there is access to all common date functions and window/udf functions

Comment: Doing this in SQL would be highly ineffective because for each row in table #2 you'd have to execute a sub query to table #1. With increasing number of rows in both tables, this would become too slow quickly. Do you really need this done in SQL? Which flavour? (MySQL, SQL Server...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if your `dates` has "all dates" you can use a `JOIN` like:

```
SELECT d.date,
    count_if(w.business_day) AS business_days_passed
FROM dates_of_interest AS d
JOIN work_days AS w
    ON date_trunc(month, d.date) = date_trunc(month, w.date) 
        AND d.date >= w.date
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

But if you Dates have gaps in them, like my example data does... you would want the LEFT JOIN form..

```
SELECT d.date,
    count_if(w.business_day) AS business_days_passed
FROM dates_of_interest AS d
LEFT JOIN work_days AS w
    ON date_trunc(month, d.date) = date_trunc(month, w.date) 
        AND d.date >= w.date
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

And using this wonderful fake data:

```
WITH work_days(date, business_day) AS (
    SELECT
        DATEADD('day', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NULL)-1, TO_DATE('1/1/2022', 'mm/dd/yyyy')) AS date
        ,DAYOFWEEKISO(date) < 6 AS business_day
    FROM TABLE(generator(ROWCOUNT => 65))
), dates_of_interest(date) AS (
    SELECT TO_DATE(column1, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
    FROM VALUES 
        ('1/1/2022'),
        ('1/2/2022'),
        ('1/3/2022'),
        ('1/4/2022'),
        ('1/15/2022'),
        ('2/2/2022'),
        ('2/11/2022'),
        ('2/12/2022')
)
```

we get:

| DATE | BUSINESS_DAYS_PASSED |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 0 |
| 2022-01-02 | 0 |
| 2022-01-03 | 1 |
| 2022-01-04 | 2 |
| 2022-01-15 | 10 |
| 2022-02-02 | 2 |
| 2022-02-11 | 9 |
| 2022-02-12 | 9 |

Comment: Thank you.  Simple, clean and effective

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple query

```
Select count(c.date) from calendar c 
Join dates_to_check d
Where month(c.date) = month(d.day)
And day(c.date) < day(d.day)
And business_Day = True;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish this with a simple `join` and a `window function`. I am assuming your date is formatted `yyyy-mm-dd` which would allow `left(date,7)` to get the year-month. If not, just use a different function to extract year-month for aggregating per month.

```
select a.date, 
       count(b.business_day) over (partition by left(a.date,7) order by a.date) business_days_elapsed
from table a
     left join calendar_table b on a.date=b.date and b.business_day='True'
group by a.date, b.business_day; --in case your data is not deduped before window function is applied
```

Comment: Thank you.! This solution seems to work well.  Doing some testing on it now

Answer (score 0):

try this with the single, table you can create a view

```
create or replace table bus_day as
SELECT column1  Date, column2   Business_Day  from values
('1/1/2021',    'False'),
('1/2/2021',    'False'),
('1/3/2021',    'True'),
('1/4/2021',    'True'),
('1/5/2021',    'True'),
('1/6/2021',    'True'),
('1/7/2021',    'True'),
('2/1/2021',    'True'),
('2/2/2021',    'True'),
('2/3/2021',    'True'),
('2/4/2021',    'True'),
('2/5/2021',    'False'),
('2/6/2021',    'False'),
('2/7/2021',    'True')
;
 
  SELECT DATE,FIRST_DAY_MONTH 
 ,row_number() over (partition by month(to_date(Date,'mm/dd/yyyy')) order by date) as row_number
 ,count_if(business_day ='True') over (partition by month(to_date(Date,'mm/dd/yyyy'))   order by DATE ) count_days
FROM (
  select Date , DATE_TRUNC('month',to_date(Date,'mm/dd/yyyy')) frst_day,
  iff(to_date(Date,'mm/dd/yyyy') = DATE_TRUNC('month',to_date(Date,'mm/dd/yyyy')), 'Y', 'N') first_day_Month , 
  business_day from bus_day order by date
   );
```